# Modify dijkstra's algorithm with some conditions

Tags: graph, dijkstra, undirected-graph

Given an undirected graph with costs on edges, find the shortest path, from given node A to B. Let's put it this way: besides the costs and edges we start at time `t = 0` and for every node you are given a list with some times that you can't pass through those nodes at that times, and you can't do anything in that time you have to wait until "it passes". As the statement says, you are a prisoner and you can teleport through the cells and the teleportation time requires the cost of the edge time, and those time when you can't do anything is when a guardian is with you in the cell and they are in the cell at every timestamp given from the list, find the minimum time to escape the prison.

What I tried:

I tried to modify it like that: in the normal dijkstra you check if it's a guardian at the minimum time you find for every node, but it didn't work.. any other ideas?

```
int checkGuardian(int min, int ind, List *guardians)
{
    for (List iter = guardians[ind]; iter; iter = iter->next)
        if(min == iter->value.node)
            return min + iter->value.node;

    return 0;
}

void dijkstra(Graph G, int start, int end, List *guardians)
{
    Multiset H = initMultiset();

    int *parent = (int *)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < G->V; ++i)
    {
        G->distance[i] = INF;
        parent[i] = -1;
    }

    G->distance[start] = 0;

    H = insert(H, make_pair(start, 0));

    while(!isEmptyMultiset(H))
    {
        Pair first = extractMin(H);

        for (List iter = G->adjList[first.node]; iter; iter = iter->next)
            if(G->distance[iter->value.node] > G->distance[first.node] + iter->value.cost 
                                                + checkGuardian(G->distance[first.node] + iter->value.cost, iter->value.node, guardians))
            {
                G->distance[iter->value.node] = G->distance[first.node] + iter->value.cost 
                                                + checkGuardian(G->distance[first.node] + iter->value.cost, iter->value.node, guardians);
                H = insert(H, make_pair(iter->value.node, G->distance[iter->value.node]));
                parent[iter->value.node] = first.node;
            }
    }

    printf("%d\n", G->distance[end]);
    printPath(parent, end);
    printf("%d\n", end);
}
```

with these structures:

```
typedef struct graph
{
    int V;
    int *distance;
    List *adjList;
} *Graph;

typedef struct list
{
    int size;
    Pair value;
    struct list *tail;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
} *List;

typedef struct multiset
{
    Pair vector[MAX];
    int size;
    int capacity;
} *Multiset;

typedef struct pair
{
    int node, cost;
} Pair;
```

As an input you are given number of nodes, number of edges and start node. For the next number of edges lines you are reading and edge between 2 nodes and the cost associated with that edge, then for the next number of nodes lines you are reading a character "N" if you can't escape from that cell and "Y" if you can escape from that cell then the number of timestamps guardians are in then number of timestamps, timestamps.
For this input:

```
6 7 1
1 2 5
1 4 3
2 4 1
2 3 8
2 6 4
3 6 2
1 5 10
N 0
N 4 2 3 4 7
Y 0
N 3 3 6 7
N 3 10 11 12
N 3 7 8 9
```

I would expect this output:

```
12
1 4 2 6 3
```

But I get this output:

```
10
1 4 2 6 3
```